# Should I spell proper nouns differently depending on the dialect I'm writing in?

Tags: spelling, dialect

I'm working on a text in British English. Should I use 'International Maritime Organization' or 'International Maritime Organisation'?

Should proper nouns keep the original or can they be spelled differently depending on dialects?

Comment: [Which spelling does the IMO itself use?](https://www.imo.org/en/About/Pages/Default.aspx)

Comment: Both spellings are acceptable in BrE.

Comment: @tchrist IMO uses "Organization", but I want to use "Organisation". I want to learn whether this is alright or not.

Comment: @AliE What kind of writing are you doing? Is this for personal writing, fiction, reporting? The default advice would be to use the official title used by the organization, but this is the kind of thing that would be covered in a style guide rather than a grammar textbook

Comment: It's actually a textbook, but everything is in British English.

Comment: If you're writing a textbook, there should be a style guide that applies, either from the publisher or from your academic institution if you have one. That said, you'll probably be fine if you write it the way you want and leave to the editors to sort out whether you've done it correctly.

Comment: As with people, organizations typically get to say what their name is and how it is spelled. If someone says their name is Fred and it's spelled "BatMan" then when writing their name, you spell Fred as "BatMan".  If the org says it's spelled "InterNational MariTime Organizhation" that's what it is.

Answer (score 4):

In your specific case (International Maritime Organization), both spellings would be acceptable since:

- the organization itself, like other UN agencies and organizations, uses the spelling "organization",
- whereas "organisation" is an accepted prevalent spelling in British English, although "organization" is also an acceptable one (but not the prevalent one), and

  - the full name of the IMO is descriptive,
  - the organization is an international one.

Whichever you choose, you should generally be consistent about the choice, both with respect to the IMO, but also the treatment of other international organizations.

---

In general though, not all proper nouns are treated the same.

It is often recommended that you follow what a person, company, or organization uses themselves to refer to themselves. This is generally a good advice: it will generally not be wrong to respect the name used by the entity in question itself.

However, this is not a strict "rule" but mostly a matter of style and preferences. There is a spectrum of acceptability to deviate from "official" names of proper nouns, which can also include political considerations.

It is almost never acceptable to modify brand names or names that are not descriptive, e.g. United Airlines, British Airways, Canadian Tire or Pepsi, especially when they are generally not translated in another Latin-character based language. But for descriptive proper nouns, the rules can be more flexible, especially for international organizations.

For example, British legislation has used both "International Maritime Organization" and "International Maritime Organisation" ([as used by the current legislation in force](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2002/1826/contents/made)); the American government often uses the spelling "International Labor Organization" (http://uscode.house.gov/view.xhtml?req=(title:22%20section:271%20edition:prelim) despite the ILO officially brands itself as the "International Labour Organization".

Comment: The spelling with 'z' is not 'wrong' in British English, though less common.

Comment: Yes, The Oxford dictionary used to prefer "z" except in specific words like "surprise".  Inspector Morse, in one of his TV shows, called the spelling with "s" as "practically illiterate".

Comment: Something that annoys me intensely is when I see US publications refer to the UK 'Labor Party'. It's a proper name. I note that the Australian LP uses the American spelling.

Comment: The OED still prefers _-ize_. According to Lynne Murphy, in _The Prodigal Tongue_, it was spellcheckers that crystallised _-ise_ in the UK: They had to add _-ise_ to their BrE dictionary, but then that ran the risk that the spelling might not be consistent in a document, so they wrongly barred _-ize_.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, it is not wrong, but not the prevalent one.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Well, the proper rules of "domestication" of "foreign" proper nouns is not something that has been settled or at least not widely agreed upon until recently. References to the British "Labor Party" can be found in many old (from 1920s) publications and current ones. The (British) Labour Party is relatively old and the name is somewhat descriptive. It was much more accepted to adapt or translate some proper nouns (including people's names, if you go further back in time).

Comment: @xngtng - I'm talking about last week, in the _New Yorker_.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, my point was that it might have been what they had always used and so they continue to use the americanized spelling. It remains a stylistic choice, one that you (and I) won't make, but not as clearly unacceptable as spelling "Canadian Tire" "Canadian Tyre", though not as widely acceptable as abbreviating UNESCO as Unesco, despite that the latter does not brand itself that way.

Comment: @xngtng - your remark about 'UNESCO' vs 'Unesco' is interesting. I try to follow the (UK) Guardian and Observer style guide in my own writing: _Use all capitals if an abbreviation is pronounced as the individual letters (an initialism): BBC, CEO, US, VAT, etc; if it is an acronym (pronounced as a word) spell out with initial capital, eg Nasa, Nato, Unicef, unless it can be considered to have entered the language as an everyday word, such as awol, laser and, more recently, asbo, pin number and sim card. Note that pdf and plc are lowercase._

Comment: @xngtng - I see the UK _Independent_ and the BBC seem to follow the _Guardian_. The _AMA Style Guide Insider_ blog, in [an article](https://amastyleinsider.com/2012/06/06/acronym-morph-whats-an-editor-to-do/) titled 'Acronym Morph: What’s an Editor to Do?' notes a 'recent' (pre-2012) trend for acronyms to morph from all-caps to initial cap/rest lower and quotes the _Chicago Manual of Style_: 'Note also that acronyms, especially those of five or more letters, tend to become lowercase with frequent use (NAFTA/Nafta, WASP/Wasp).” '

Comment: @xngtng - a more refined Google search shows recent and not-so-recent occurrences of both 'British Labor Party' and 'British Labour Party' in the _New Yorker_.